# Exchange data between an sql and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am about to learn sql and I have a question.Is it possible to use jquery(or php) to collect data(and add) from an sql database?
I would like a detailed answer

Comment: The detailed answer is "Yes, use Jquery's $.ajax(), $.post(), or $.get() methods...." That's it. Oh, and you have to use both JS and PHP, not just one.

Comment: @adeneo If you can see i say "about to learn".I don't know sql

Comment: Then you need to learn a bit about SQL, and that's too large a topic for an answer on StackOverflow: but there's a lot of tutorials on Ajax and PHP, on PHP and SQL, and on SQL on the interweb.... make sure you use one that teaches how to use bind variables with MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but your question is very broad.Check out the tutorials that [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) provide, in my experience these are a great way to get started and provide great tutorials on PHP, SQL and jQuery.

Comment: w3schools really isn't a good resource for tutorials: too many errors in what they teach

Comment: Fair enough but personally I found it a great resource that consolidated many subject areas. I am not saying it's perfect but I found it great for understanding some basic concepts which I could then build upon as a beginner.

Comment: I have to agree .It's not the best site but it helps you with the basic things